Client registration for chat application using erlang
I'm newbie to erlang. I have been working on a group chat application using erlang. The thing come into my mind is how to allow users to sign up for an account filling some information such as email address, user name and password. So for that case, how to do this theoretically ? i.e., in witch format I should store the user information into a file and how?
May I have a simple example in how to do it programmatically? I can read the user inputs from the console, but, how to deal with these information and save it in a file to be used later when user attempt to login?

You're going to find that you can accomplish this with far less code than you might think, but you'll be spending a good deal of time in the OTP documentation.
The standard structure for such a service is an application (a behavior) module that starts a supervisor (another behavior) module that contains a process servicing each logged-in user, most likely implementing another behavior (check the gen_... family).
So, a simple way to store your user records would be in dets (Durable Erlang Term Storage). This won't serve your needs if you scale up beyond a demo project, but it'll get you started with storing, finding, and retrieving user records in a file.
All of those names I highlighted are modules in the erlang distribution, documented here: https://www.erlang.org/doc/man_index.html
If you post some code with a specific problem you're trying to figure out I'm sure you'll get more focused answers. Happy coding!

how to implement another behavior beside the message passing behavior please ?
